# media is write protected when using diskshadow.exe, start-bitstransfer powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, vss, bits

i am trying to use the powershell start-bitstransfer cmdlets to transfer a file i have exposed using a vss snapshot (via diskshadow), but unfortunately i am receiving the following error:

> Start-BitsTransfer : The media is write protected.
>   At line:1 char:49
>   + Import-CSV c:\hda1\bits.txt | start-bitstransfer <<<<  -transfertype upload -Authentication "Basic" -Credential $cred
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBits
>      TransferCommand

we really want to utilize the bits endpoint we are attempting to transfer the files to. is there any other way we can go about this (aside from copying the files elsewhere first, unless we can copy one slice at a time and transfer that)?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem as you. The only way around this is by using bits via http. I am using the [bits compact server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd904465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The bits compact server is managed with wmi. Following code can create a url for a file:

```
## Get BITS Compact Server WMI Class
$bcs = [wmiclass] "root\Microsoft\bits:Bitscompactserverurlgroup"

## Create URLGroup
$bcs.CreateUrlGroup("http://+:80/Demo/")

## Get created URLGroups object
$urlgroup = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\Microsoft\bits" -Class Bitscompactserverurlgroup" -Filter "urlgroup='http://+:80/Demo/'"

## Host a file. The file has to be present and accessible"
$urlgroup.CreateUrl("file.dat", "F:\shadow\bits1\file.dat", "")
```

(code from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/08/18/bits-compact-server-wmi-provider.aspx)

Now you can download the file using

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "http://localhost/demo/file.dat" -Destination j:\
```